# Why the last line send me a 0 answers

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I want to change all the formulas in an excel reporting into a VBA macro.
I have a table with all my supplier and I want a sum in another column.
For that I have to a Sumifs function, the results send me 0 for each line and I don't know why

```
Dim NSynthese As Worksheet
Dim NTABLEAU As Worksheet
Dim Source_CAS As Worksheet
Dim CAS_offres As Worksheet
Dim FP_offres As Worksheet
Dim lderLigne_source_CAS As Long
Dim lderLigne_NTABLEAU As Long
Dim ddate_CAS_max As Date
Dim h As Long   

 With Application.WorksheetFunction

            For h = 4 To lderLigne_NTABLEAU

            NTABLEAU.Cells(h + 1, 8).Value = .SumIfs(Source_CAS.Columns("T"), _
                                                     Source_CAS.Columns("AE"), _
                                                     NTABLEAU.Cells(h + 1, 4), _
                                                     Source_CAS.Columns("C"), _
                                                     ddate_CAS_max)

            Next h
    End with
```

I don't have a message error just a "-" result in each cells `(NTABLEAU.Cells(h + 1, 8))` and I expect a number

the excel formula is

```
: =SOMME.SI.ENS(Source_CAS!T:T;Source_CAS!AE:AE;NTABLEAU!D9;Source_CAS!C:C;datemax_CAS);
```

ddate_CAS_max is a date that I also put in the cell named datemax_CAS. 
the excel formula works.

The mistake was in the definition of the date, 
I put :

```
NSynthese.Range("datemax_CAS").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Source_CAS.Range("c2:c" & lderLigne_source_CAS))
```

instead of :

```
ddate_CAS_max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Source_CAS.Range("c2:c" & lderLigne_source_CAS))
NSynthese.Range("datemax_CAS").Value = ddate_CAS_max
```

Comment: It's going to be very hard for us to help. We don't know what your original formula was, and we don't have any data to reproduce this issue. What have you tried as far as debugging this yourself? What is `ddate_CAS_max`?

Comment: So you're summing up Column `T` if Column `O` matches your looping column `D`, and if Column `C` matches `ddate_CAS_max`, which we don't know what that is.  Please verify that is correct, just incase you're having the criterion in incorrect columns.  Note that you can write `Columns("T")` and it will work the same as `Columns(20)`.

Comment: Verify that none of the columns are *formatted as text* - the `-` result looks like the result is an accounting-formatted `0`. Is the sum of `Source_CAS.Columns(20)` a numeric value? The `ddate_CAS_max` is a prime suspect: make sure Excel understands all the dates *as dates*, not just text that *looks like it's a date*.